# When is it appropriate to use a paired Wilcoxon test?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

Could someone please explain in plain English (preferably without using the word paired) or by using examples when it is appropriate to use `wilcox.test(x,y,paired=TRUE)`?

I have read the R documentation and various links on google and I'm not 100% sure that I get it. If someone would be kind enough just to explain it simply I would feel much happier going ahead and using it on my data.

At the minute I think it's appropriate to compare data like `amount.on.monday` and `amount.on.friday` but not for comparing `time.i.eat` and `amount.on.monday`?

```
time.i.eat=c(1,2,3,4)
amount.on.monday=c(1,1,1,1)
amount.on.friday=c(2,2,2,2)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(Sorry, but I will have to use the word "paired")

There are two aspects to this question: 
1) When to use paired tests
2) When to use Wilcoxon

Paired tests are appropriate when the data are not independent and when the dependency results in a 1 to 1 match. For example suppose I want to study heights of men and women. If I gather 100 random men and 100 random women, the data are independent: Bob's height has nothing to do with Mary's height. But if I gather data on 100 brother/sister pairs, the data are *not* independent: Siblings will share lots of factors that affect height. And, since they are brother sister pairs, a paired test works.

Wilcoxon tests (as opposed to t-tests, e.g.) are non-parametric. They do not assume things about the distributions. When the data are very non-normal, t-tests may not be appropriate and one alternative is Wilcoxon. In addition, Wilcoxon tests entire distributions whereas t-tests are tests of the means.

Comment: I can forgive you for using the word paired - that's very clear to me now, thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This may be a dump question, but which one is better between paired wilcoxon and unpaired wilcoxon for significance tests?

Comment: One isn't better or worse - they are used in different situations.